# Why does my iPod shuffle occasionally fail to sync play counts with iTunes?

Tags: itunes, ipod-shuffle

It's been about half a year since I moved from an iPhone to a Windows Phone. This was a particularly difficult decision, as play counts are extremely important to me but non-Apple devices don't sync media play counts with iTunes. (More on this in a bit.)

But I switched anyway, and I bought a 4th-generation iPod shuffle as a replacement for the Music app on my iPhone as well as a cool little fashion accessory in my favorite color. I never listen to any music from my iTunes library on my Windows Phone; the only music-related thing I do with it is watch music videos on the Internet — I don't store any music videos on iTunes anyway.

In the six and a half years I'd been using an iPhone, play counts and other metadata synced *perfectly* with iTunes (well, except when it was completely fudged in iOS 8.0 until it was fixed several months later in iOS 8.1.1). Not so with my iPod shuffle; I've noticed that when I sync, sometimes the play counts, skip counts and last played/skipped dates update, and other times they *don't* even though I could have sworn I've been listening to my music all day.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't think of posting this question until today but after a few weeks of experimentation, I've determined that, for some strange reason, iPod shuffle will only update play metadata when, before my next sync, I either

1. finish listening to a playlist, or
2. switch from one playlist to another.

If I don't finish listening to a playlist (which can be the case with very large playlists), the metadata will **not** be updated on iTunes.

Powering iPod shuffle off and on between listens does not appear to make a difference, but I'll report back with any new findings. For what it's worth, in normal use, these are the steps I take when preparing to sync:

1. Power off iPod shuffle by sliding the three-way switch to OFF.
2. Disconnect the earphones.
3. Connect iPod shuffle to the USB cable.
4. Sync.

And of course I always eject it from iTunes before disconnecting it.

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently it works to tick the 'Auto fill' option in the ipod 'Music' menu](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1466623). I have not been able to actually test this, and this *is* pretty annoying if you only want a couple of hours of music on your ipod and have to fill it with some 300 songs.

I have noticed that with certain very long tracks, ipod never syncs the play count. With other tracks, it seems to be random, yet the exception, luckily. Still, it is bl**dy annoying, and seems like a very simple thing to fix for a multizillion company like Apple.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.